# How can I prevent users from getting a higher score illegitimately on a javascript game?

Tags: javascript, php, database

I'm creating a game site and when a player has finished playing the game, I want the site to update the score to a database. Now my only problem is, the player can easily cheat their score by using javascript methods/code in the browser. How can I do this?

Comment: then you should sanitise it before putting it into the database...

Comment: Store the game scores in PHP variables as soon as the game ends. Whatever is stored in javascript can be neglected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent Javascript games tweaking/hacking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320996/prevent-javascript-games-tweaking-hacking)

Answer (score 0):

> The player can easily cheat their score by using javascript methods/code in the browser.

**Obfuscation:** If your goal is to prevent it from happening **easily**, you can [obfuscate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-protect-javascript) your JavaScript code.  **Edit:** After reading [@mickmackusa's link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320996/), [`IIFE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8228308/3196753)'s are a quick way to achieve what you're looking for.

**Signatures:** If your goal is to prevent it from happening ever, you should consider using a [verifiable signature or hash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27041297/3196753).  The more JS-heavy the app, the harder this can get.  For example, if the signature is generated client-side via pure JavaScript, your code [would still leak everything an attacker would need to fake the signature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15220089/3196753).  The accepted design is to move the private components server-side where they can be protected.

Obfuscation is quite effective so as long as the burden of deobfuscating is far greater greater than the rewards (or risks) associated with an attacker figuring it out.

Comment: All I need to make sure is that the score sent to the database is the correct score

Comment: Minimizing the way the problem sounds does not affect the end-solution.  If you need to guarantee the the authenticity, use a verifiable unalterable method.  If you want to filter out 99% of hackers make the code so confusing that even you can't understand after studying it how it's sent to the back-end.

Comment: Assuming the problem happens mostly when people are on a scoreboard asked for their name, you may also choose to use a unique ID for each score in the database and then have the final screen which asks for the name to simply modify that record.  This still isn't foolproof and I would recommend you store some form of timestamp on session so that someone doesn't wipe your database clean.  It's still a poor design though.  If you want it secured, you'll need to use a secure, trusted method of data signing.